# Objectify / datastore query with inequality filters on multiple datastore properties

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am trying to use google app engine datastore in which i need to get the total salary of an employee for 2 date range. I need to provide the range of hour i.e. startDate and endDate so how can i do this on datastore. I am using objectify in app engine datastore.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at the [objectify wiki](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Queries). In the section *Executing Queries* there are samples on how to create basic queries.

Lets assume your entity looks something like this

```
@Entity
public class Salary {
  Ref<Employee> employee;
  @Id 
  Long salaryId;
  @Index
  Date startDate;
  @Index
  Date endDate;
  Long salaryCents;
}
```

If you want to create a query that takes a minimum data and a maximum date value into account you can chain filters like so:

```
ofy().load(Salary.class).filter("startDate >", start).filter("startDate <=", end).list();
```

As you can read in the [datastore docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries) under section *Inequality filters are limited to at most one property' you **cannot** filter by two different properties with inequality filters, thus making a query like

```
ofy().load(Salary.class).filter("startDate >", start).filter("endDate <=", end).list();
```

impossible.

What you can do though is to filter by one property and filter the the other property in-memory in your Java code.

An alternative approach (that should be possible although i haven't tried it) would be to get a list of keys for your first filter like so:

```
Iterable<Key<Salary>> keys = ofy().load(Salary.class).filter("startDate >", start).keys();
```

and then use the keys in a second query like so:

```
ofy().load(Salary.class).filter("salaryId IN", keys).filter("endDate <=", end).list();
```

Note that an IN filter will perform multiple queries, so the in-memory approach could be faster, depending on your data.

Ideally you can reduce your query to just one property that requires an inequality filter.

Comment: It is a better approach but I am getting IllegalArgumentException: id: com.googlecode.objectify.Key is not a supported property type.

Comment: @Prasanna please provide your code or open a new question. I cannot tell why you get an exception from your comment.